# UTF8 encoding with special foreign characters

Tags: php, mysql

PHP piece of code like this:

```
trim(strtolower(utf8_encode($res->translation))) == trim(strtolower(utf8_encode($ph)))
```

returns false if, for example:`$res->translation = "Bottines À Talons Hauts"` and `$ph = "bottines à talons hauts"`. The problem should be in a weird `À` letter, as other words match perfectly.

It needs to be mentioned that `$res->translation` comes from MySQL and `$ph` is a phrase from textarea in HTML page.

Any ideas?

Comment: what you want to do? What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

> Returns string with all alphabetic characters converted to lowercase.
>
> Note that 'alphabetic' is determined by the current locale. This means that in i.e. the default "C" locale, characters such as umlaut-A (Ä) will not be converted.

This should be solved using mb_strtolower and forcing UTF-8

```
trim(mb_strtolower(utf8_encode($res->translation),'UTF-8')) == trim(mb_strtolower(utf8_encode($ph),'UTF-8'))
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for. Just little change though `trim(mb_strtolower($res->translation, 'UTF-8')) == trim(mb_strtolower($ph, 'UTF-8'))`. Don't need utf8_encode function anymore.

Answer (score 0):

May be your database connection needs to be established using utf8 encoding.

Try following when establishing your connection:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```

Note: Better to use mysqli or PDO, though